# grunt Unexpected token : error

Tags: gruntjs

I followed http://gruntjs.com/getting-started to install grunt on my Ubuntu 11.10. When I ran grunt, I got this error:

```
/opt/node-v0.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/package.json:2
  "name": "grunt-cli",
        ^

node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/node-v0.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/lib/info.js:13:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
```

I previously used grunt 0.3.16. I am upgrading to the latest grunt. It doesn't seem to be related to my project. I get this error in any directory.

Comment: Did you uninstall grunt first with `npm uninstall -g grunt`?

Comment: I did. I even reinstalled node.js to get a new npm, and still got this. Currently under the lib/node_modules of my node.js directory, I only see grunt-cli and npm.

Comment: I also made sure my current grunt is run from under grunt-cli/bin/grunt.

Comment: For some reason, the installed grunt-cli `package.json` seems to be invalid. Perhaps try reinstalling grunt-cli.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I didn't install node.js correctly. I simply untar the node.js binary and added it to my path. I guess that is why it didn't work. I download the node.js source, compiled and installed it using make, and it works now. Thanks for all your comments.